# procedure for delete records from tables Related to each other

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, cascading-deletes

My tables have these structures (in oracle):

```
---table grandmother ---
  ID
  some other columns


---table mother---
  ID
  grandmother_ID
  some other columns

---table girl
  ID
  mother_ID
  some other columns

---table grandchild1
  ID
  girl_ID
  some other columns 

---table grandchild2
  ID
  girl_ID
  some other columns
```

Now, how can i write a procedure to delete one record from grandmother table ? It is clear that we should delete records with grandmother_IDs from mother table and mother_IDs from girl table and girl_IDs from grandchild1 and grandchild2.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE GRAND_MOTHER_DELETE
( 
    IN_ID      IN      GRAND_MOTHER.ID%TYPE 
 )
 AS 
 BEGIN

  DELETE FROM GRAND_CHILD1 GC1 , GRAND_CHILD2 GC2 USING GC1 , GC2
  WHERE GC1.GIRL_ID = GC2.GIRL_ID
  AND GC2.GIRL_ID IN(   
  SELECT ID FROM GIRL WHERE MOTHER_ID IN (
  SELECT ID FROM MOTHER WHERE GRAND_MOTHER_ID=IN_ID));      

  DELETE
  FROM   GRAND_MOTHER
  WHERE  ID  = IN_ID; 

 END;
```

But it gives syntax error.

Comment: Start by deleting the  grandchildren and move upwards.

Comment: @KaushikNayak Can you explain in more detail?

Comment: First delete rows from GRANDCHILD2. Then from GRANDCHILD1.Then from GIRL. Etc. If you created foreign key constraint(s) as `ON DELETE CASCADE`, you could have deleted parent, and Oracle would delete children.

Comment: @Littlefoot  ON DELETE CASCADE solved my problem.

Comment: Nice; I'm glad you made it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @Littlefoot answer, I add `ON DELETE CASCADE` in grandchild1, grandchild2, girl and mother tables and my problem solved.